# Pass Data back through Push Segue Back Button

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I will do my best to articulate what exactly my question and issue is and hopefully provide enough code to help. I'm making a recipe app where the initial screen is a tableview and you click the "add button" which pops up the "Add Recipe View Controller" and you enter the recipe information into the Text Fields (name, cook time, prep time, etc...). You hit "Save" which has an Unwind Segue back to the TableView which adds the new recipe. The initial table view shows the Recipe Name, Prep Time, and Category all accurately. When you click on the specific recipe (tableview row) it performs a push segue to the "Recipe Detail View Controller" which shows everything you entered in the "add recipe" view controller all through labels. My question now comes when I want to edit this information. I have gotten as far as being able to click "edit" and bringing you back to the "add recipe view controller" where you can edit the information and change any of the information you need. When I click save, it takes you back to the "Recipe Detail View Controller" and all of the information is changed accurately. My issue and question is how do I make it so it saves back to the table view so when I click the Back Button from the push segue, the tableview information reflects the changes and everything is saved.

This is my code when a user clicks save from editing the recipe and dismisses the view controller and goes back to "Recipe Detail View Controller"

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if saveButton === sender {
        let name2 = recipeNameField.text ?? ""
        let photo2 = photoImageView.image
        let source2 = sourceField.text ?? ""
        let category2 = categoryField.text ?? ""
        let servings2 = servingsField.text ?? ""
        let prepTime2 = prepTimeField.text ?? ""
        let cookTime2 = cookTimeField.text ?? ""
        let sourceURL2 = sourceURLField.text ?? ""

        newRecipe = Recipe(name: name2, servings: servings2, category: category2, prepTime: prepTime2, cookTime: cookTime2, source: source2, sourceURL: sourceURL2, photo: photo2)
    }
}
```

Right now I have an Unwing segue to go from the Recipe Detail View Controller to the table view which works and updates the table view information, but the load time is way to long and sometimes crashes. I would much rather find a way for it to save across the board when I hit "Save" from the "Edit Recipe View Controller" and just use the Back Button from the push segue.

Below is the Unwind segue code I have now to get back to the TableView

```
@IBAction func unwindToMyRecipesFromDetail(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? RecipeDetailViewController, indrecipe = sourceViewController.recipeDetail {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            // Update an existing meal.
            recipes2[selectedIndexPath.row] = indrecipe
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        } else {
            // Add a new meal.
            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: recipes2.count, inSection: 0)
            recipes2.append(indrecipe)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if myRecipesButton === sender {
        let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! RecipeListTableViewController

        let name2 = recipeNameLabel.text ?? ""
        let photo2 = recipeImage.image
        let source2 = sourceLabel.text ?? ""
        let category2 = categoryLabel.text ?? ""
        let servings2 = servingsLabel.text ?? ""
        let prepTime2 = prepTimeLabel.text ?? ""
        let cookTime2 = cookTimeLabel.text ?? ""
        let sourceURL2 = recipeDetail!.sourceURL ?? ""

        recipeDetail = Recipe(name: name2, servings: servings2, category: category2, prepTime: prepTime2, cookTime: cookTime2, source: source2, sourceURL: sourceURL2, photo: photo2)

        destVC.recipes3 = recipeDetail

    }
}
```

Comment: Which ViewControllers do you have the `prepareForSegue` functions in?

Comment: the last prepare for segue function is in the Recipe Detail View Controller that is taking you back to the table view by way of an Unwind Segue because I couldn't get it to save the data when it was just a "back button" from the push segue.

Comment: I think it may be your `if ____Button === sender` lines that are problematic. Trying checking against the segue instead of the sender.   i.e. `if segue.Identifier == "whateverYouNameIt"` and be sure to name the segue identifier with the same string in your storyboard.

Comment: You should use the unwind segue to go back when the user clicks 'cancel' while editing or creating a recipe and define a new push segue when clicking 'save' button.